# Configure wiremock with two distinct scenarios with the same url

Tags: wiremock

It is possible to configure wiremock with two distinct scenarios?

So the first scenario name is "server error 3 times" will send certain responses on same URL to simulate server error for 3 times and then return a successful response.

The second different scenario name is "authorization error 3 times" similar to the previous one with the same url but will return 403 three times the a successful response.

```
Server error 3 times: 
1st request -> 503 response
2nd request -> 503 response
3rd request -> 503 response
4th request -> 200 response
```

```
Authorization error 3 times: 
1st request -> 403 response
2nd request -> 403 response
3rd request -> 403 response
4th request -> 200 response
```

I couldn't figure out how to implement such scenarios in wiremock.

Comment: Is there anything that differentiates the two scenarios? Two different logins, headers, etc?

Comment: No, they are identical. The only difference is the response based on the service. The first one will return a server error, assuming that the server has a problem and the second one is the same as the first one, but the provided credentials are wrong. I see your point, and if there is no other way to tell Wiremock which one to trigger, then I have to use different credentials for each to trigger the intended scenario. I ask Bing AI, and in the provided answer, it passed the `scenarioName` in the query parameter of the request.